# two methods inside render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails beginner and I'm trying to render on my show (as in tv show) page

"@reviews by @sources"

and I'm not sure how to add a second method inside my render in my views
shows

controller:

```
 def show
   @show = Show.find(params[:id])
   @reviews = @show.reviews.paginate(page: params[:page])
   @sources = @show.reviews.source

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @show }

  end
end
```

show view show.html.erb

```
   <div class="span8">
   <% if @show.reviews.any? %>
   <h3>Reviews (<%= @show.reviews.count %>)</h3>
   <ol class="reviews">
   <%= render @reviews %>
   </ol>
   <%= will_paginate @reviews %>
   <% end %>
   </div>
   </div>
```

any help ?!

Comment: The question is not very clear, are you asking how to access different formats ? Can u be more specific

Comment: I'm asking how to have: "the review" by "the review source" on the tv show's page (in that    <%= render @reviews %>)

Comment: @CharlieAllombert You should spend some time on [Rails Tutorial Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) to get acquainted with the Rails way. Your code sample shows a total lack of appreciation for the difference between `collections` and `attributes`. `@reviews` is a set of reviews. `source` is an attribute of one `review`; so it  shouldn't be assigned to a `@sources` variable. Also, `<%= render @reviews %>` is valid in a view. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#highlighter_850708 to undrestand how it is interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a will paginate array called @reviews. this array has review objects. Now to display the contents of this array, what you need to do is, in the show.htm.erb.

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <%= review.column_name %>
<% end %>
```

The render method, which you have used is a method from ActionController, you can't use that in the views.

Comment: Unfortunately can't as I'm a new user!